# how to keep form data from nativescript-localstorage when routing in another component and return back in first component

Tags: typescript, local-storage, nativescript

In my project you find [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=SLeiAE), I want to save my data in storage, and display it in the form. The data is always displayed at home when there are data in storage, if the wifi parameter local storge is empty, and the form will be blank. If the wifi parameter is with the 'Mywifi' value in the local storage, the form will also show 'Mywifi'

Image[Image with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cYn8.png)
Image [Image with empty input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGlrB.png)

Please can you ask me any idea how to display data in form?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'll need more information to properly help you: what have you tried so far (including your code), what specifically is going wrong, and do you have a minimal working example of the issue? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is use the `FormGroup` methods, `.getRawValue()` to get the form data as Object and `.patchValue(data)` to set the form value from Object.

Also you must use `routerExtensions.back()` to navigate back to the page where you came from. Using `router.navigate(...)` will keep opening new instances of home page here.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // Needs relative path to work with Playground
    let LS = require("../nativescript-localstorage");
    // Make sure you don't apply invalid values from your previous cache, you will get invalid boolean exception if then
    this.ConfigurationForm.patchValue(JSON.parse(LS.getItem(ConfigurationComponent.CURRENT_CONFIG) || "{}"));
}

register() {
    // Needs relative path to work with Playground
    let LS = require("../nativescript-localstorage");
    LS.setItem(ConfigurationComponent.CURRENT_CONFIG, JSON.stringify(this.ConfigurationForm.getRawValue()));
    this.routerExtensions.back();
}
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=SLeiAE&v=2)